Mysql Stuck at "Server shutdown in progress" state
My MySQL was not responsive and I tried restarting the MySql server. Now for more than 2 hrs, it's stuck at the "Server shutdown in progress" stage. I need to bring the service back as soon as production is down. Please suggest what can be done here.
Thanks in advance.

Check local server console, check for disk activity and wait until it's done. You could also tell us more about your SQL server.

Any specific command output is needed?

Of course, anything that might be a hint why this server needs so long for shutting down.

Any specific command output is needed? The MySQL server is Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu)). And the storage is an extended logical volume.

Also 126G space is left on the device.

Hi any help would be highly appreciated. How can I get this back to running state? would rebooting the server be of any help?

Check mysqladmin processlist. It's possible some nasty query really is still running. Mysqld shouldn't start any new queries when it is reporting shutdown in progress.
If it really is idle, then try mysqladmin shutdown. This is probably the command used in your unit file but worth running again. Give it a few minutes. If still running, try killall -TERM mysqld - again wait a few minutes.
If the service is still running, then you'll need to crash mysqld to get it to stop: killall -KILL mysqld. Expect the startup to take longer with a chance of data corruption.
